# Передача значений формы в PHP

Tags: php, html

Здравствуйте!

есть простая страница авторизации:

```
<form class="form-signin" action = "php/loginServer.php" method = "POST">
 <label class="radio">
    <input type="radio" name="worker" value="1" checked/>
          Продавец
 </label>
<label class="radio">
    <input type="radio" name="worker" value="2"/> 
          Менеджер
</label>
<input type="text" class="input-block-level" placeholder="Email address" name="email">
<input type="password" class="input-block-level" placeholder="Password" name ="pass">
```

---

на сервере:

```
$email = $_POST['email'];
$loginPassword = $_POST['pass'];    
$worker = $_POST['worker'];
```

Первых два поля получаю нормально, а вот значение переключателя не передается. Подскажите, что не так делаю?

Comment: @PavelNET, присоединяясь к ответу ниже - внешне все выглядит вполне прилично, возможно, где-то удаляется `$_POST['worker']`

Answer (score 1):

В следующем виде у меня все прекрасно работает. При нажатии submit все переменные оказываются в массиве $_POST. Если все же не получается, можете выложить побольше кода в комментарий.

```
<form class="form-signin" action = "test.php" method = "POST">
     <label class="radio">
        <input type="radio" name="worker" value="1" checked/>
              Продавец
     </label>
    <label class="radio">
        <input type="radio" name="worker" value="2"/> 
              Менеджер
    </label>
    <input type="text" class="input-block-level" placeholder="Email address" name="email">
    <input type="password" class="input-block-level" placeholder="Password" name ="pass">`
    <input type="submit">
```

php

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте заменить конструкцию

```
<label class="radio"> <input type="radio" name="worker" value="1" checked/> Продавец </label>
<label class="radio"> <input type="radio" name="worker" value="2"/> Менеджер </label>
```

на следующую

```
<input id="radio1" type="radio" name="worker" value="1" checked="checked"/><label for="radio1"> Продавец </label>
<input id="radio2" type="radio" name="worker" value="2"/><label for="radio2"> Менеджер </label>
```

Comment: К сожалению, не помогло.